# How to interpolate a regex into string and use that string as regex to compare in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Consider i have a strings

```
goo = "test check\ncode"

if goo =~ /#{Regexp.quote(foo)}/
  puts "success!"
end
```

I need to compare with "foo" regex. How can i write this regex?

Kindly help me in to find this!

Comment: What is `foo` and why do you want to / have to _"interpolate a regex into string and use that string as regex"_ in the first place? Maybe a more detailed example would help.

Comment: @user3784251: Please _DO NOT_ post your code in comments. You can edit your question to include the code snippet you want, and it will be much clearer and easier to read. And, as it stands, your question is not answerable, because you've left out key details that might allow someone else to actually solve your problem instead of having to guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `foo` contains a string, which represents the regexp. If so, you can initialize `Regexp` object from that string and perform your matching as follows:

```
foo = 'test.*check.*code'

goo =~ Regexp.new(foo, Regexp::MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Take a look at [Regexp documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html). `.` matches any character except a newline. Unless you initialize the Regexp object to work with multiline code. Check out my updated ansfer.

Answer (score 2):

```
goo = "test check\ncode"
foo = "test.*check.*code"

goo =~ /#{foo}/m
#⇒ 0
```

The reason why your regexp did not do the trick, is that you have to explicitly set `.` to match new lines with `m` Regexp modifier.